# RxJava or F# function [List<String> to Map<Integer, String>] where Integer is the position where String changes

Tags: android, functional-programming, rx-java

I am trying to extract a Map of headers (position of the header + text in the header) from a list of inputs. I have mapped the inputs to the header (or group) they belong in. I need a function that's more or less like `distinct`or `distinctUntilChanged`but where I can obtain the position where the text changed.

So far I have this:

```
Observable.from(inputs)
            .map(this::getSectionTitle) // Maps the inputs into the Header string
            .distinct();
```

which obviously return a list of the headers. In case it wasn't clear I need the list of headers linked to the position where they should be placed.

Alternatively I can also accept a function in F#  of type `List<String> -> Set<(Int*String)>`for example.

**Edit:**

This is the function I want to move from impeartive to a functionl approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
        Input pu = inputs.get(i);
        String header = getSectionTitle(pu);
        if (!mHeaders.containsValue(header)) {
            mHeaders.put(i + mHeaders.size(), header);
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

Example of an input/output

`["a","a","a","b","b","c"]  ->  [("a",0),("b",3),("c",5)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
 Observable.from(inputs)
        .map(this::getSectionTitle) // Maps the inputs into the Header string
        .zipWith(Observable.range(0, 1000), Pair::create) // This is a weak point of the solution as you should know max number of emissions as if it exceeds the number in range, it will stop emitting .. 
        .distinctUntilChanged(pair -> pair.first) // keySelector function tells the operator what is the value object upon which it should determine whether it was changed
        .map(pair -> /* Map to your desired format */)
```

The pair corresponds to an item which has changed and the order number, in which it was emitted...

***EDIT***: Instead of Observable.range() you can use timer with scan operator. You should not rely on direct emissions from timer observable as there is no guarantee that it will be a continuous sequence, therefore a scan operator.

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .scan(0L, (index, emittedValue) -> index++)
```

Comment: That doesn't help me much :(  What I need is a distinctUntilChanged() (or combination of functions) that emits the position where the element changed. Let's say I have an array [a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,d]. I want the Observable to emit [(a,0),(b,3),(c,5),(d,8)] for example. Your solution would emit [[a,b],[c,d]] ignoring the skip 1

Comment: That looks almost perfect.  Is there a way to create an infinite stream instead of Observable.range(0,1000)?

Comment: There is, but the only one and most probably the simplest solution will limit your emission frequency. If you use `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).scan(0L, (index, emittedValue) -> index++)`, you will create an infinite stream.. But I am uncertain if zipWith operator can handle emission overflow, so be careful with too small frequency.

Comment: does the zip operator lazily evaluate the other observables? By that I mean, is the Observable.range(0,1000) completely evaluating so the .zip operator is buffering the 1000 integers? Or does it evaluate on a one-by-one fashion? I hope this was clear